# Facebook Connect - Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting this error when trying to logout of facebook connect

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

```
function facebook_logout(){

        $user = $_SESSION[ 'facebook_userid' ];

        $facebook = new Facebook( array(

            'appId'  => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,

        ) );

        $_SESSION[ 'facebook_userid' ] = "";
        $_SESSION[ 'logged' ] = FALSE;
        $url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

        header( "Location: $url" );

}

facebook_logout();
```

Comment: It is hard to debug without the complete code, or seeing the live application. But it seems pretty clear that your're logging out the user, then he is redirected to a page where you probably log him out again.